# Error when running mvn sonar:sonar

Tags: maven

I'm trying to set up sonar locally. I have sonar running on port 9000. When I run mvn sonar:sonar on my project I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (d
efault-cli) on project myProject: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:s
onar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar failed: A required class was missing while executing
org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/depend
ency/tree/DependencyTreeBuilder;
```

Does anyone no why it is not picking up the correct version of DependencyTreeBuilder?

Comment: hmm...seems like it was a corrupted POM, I deleted the maven-dependency-tree folder from my local maven repo and did a clean install. fixed.